# JQuery SyntaxHighLighter Plugin in tinyMCE iframe

Tags: jquery-plugins, tinymce, syntaxhighlighter

i find a question about SyntaxHighlighter .

But , i'm talking about the jquery plugin and Not  https://github.com/RichGuk/syntaxhl

I want to highlight source code in tinyMCE 
I add the following button :

```
ed.addButton('srccd', {
                     title: 'Source Code',
                     image: 'sourcecode.png',
                     onclick: function() {
                         ed.focus();       
                         var newSRCjq='<pre id="s1" class="highlight">'+ ed.selection.getContent() + '</pre>';
                         ed.selection.setContent(newSRCjq);


                           $.SyntaxHighlighter.init({})

                     }
                 });
```

i use also another plugin (snippet),and instead of init invoke , i call the following function :

```
 $('iframe').contents().find('#s1').snippet("java",{style:'kwrite',box:"1"});
```

and i don't reach to expected result.

NOTE : I don't forget to import required JS & CSS for plugins above

Answer (score 0):

After one day : 
Let's introduce my  [JQuery Compiler](https://github.com/abdennour/compiler.snippetplugin) which is a compiler based on  [jQuery Syntax Highlighter v2.0.0](http://steamdev.com/snippet) :

How To Use

Instead of :

```
$('pre').snippet('java',{box:"1-2"});
```

Add local or session argument:

```
$('pre').snippetcache('local','java',{box:"1-2"});
```

==>That's mean that you have `pre` elements . When you run the snippet above , My plugin will compile the code using `jQuery Syntax Highlighter` , and then save the rendered code  . So, if another `pre` has the same code(inner text) such as one of previous `pre` compiled , the compiler will retrieve the rendered code form its cache .

However , when you refresh page , Cache will be removed . If you want to have a stateful compiler , use session argument value instead of local

```
$('pre').snippetcache('session','java',{box:"1-2"});
```

## See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/ZRqhG/) .

This is plugin is very useful in iframe as tinyMCE. In fact , Try this :

```
    ed.addButton('srccd', {
                         title: 'Source Code',
                         image: 'sourcecode.png',
                         onclick: function() {
                             ed.focus();   
                                //You should have an ID which is generated automatically     
                             var newSRCjq='<pre id="s1" class="highlight">'+ ed.selection.getContent() + '</pre>';
                             ed.selection.setContent(newSRCjq);

                       // iframe selected is the frame of TinyMCE  

                   $('iframe').contents.find('pre#s1').snippetcache('local','java',{box:"1-2"});




                 }
             });
```